# Using powershell to manipulate URL header with real live system data

Tags: powershell, web, automation

I am trying to use powershell to manipulate a url value for a command program that is accessing a web Url.

Basically the case is like this

run in Powershell:

Program Argument https://www.example.com/dash/926846/l.php?link=bTP77O5LyLorxCtjnkdE0g&sectime=1598048132

The Sectime is in Unix time format. What i am trying to do is :

use the powershell command (Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s) to generate the system time in real time,

Append the result to the end of the Url as a value for sectime.

I tried to concatnate the arguments using call operator :

```
Arg1=program
Arg2=parameter
Arg3=Url
& $Arg1 Arg2 $Arg3
```

now the issue is i can do

this is the issue. & $Arg1 Arg2 $Arg3 and that works , but i can not modify the URL to take the real time command (Get- Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)
if i split the URL arg into two i cant not concatnate them like this

"https://www.example.com/dash/926846/l.php?link=bTP77O5LyLorxCtjnkdE0g&sectime=(Get-Date -Date ((Get-Date).DateTime) -UFormat %s)."

Since it is a string and an command

An idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$uriTemplate = 'https://www.example.com/dash/{0}/l.php?link={1}&sectime={2}'

$id = '926846'
$link = 'bTP77O5LyLorxCtjnkdE0g'
$timeunixseconds =  [System.DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()

$uriSting = [String]::Format($uriTemplate, # Template with placeholders {0}, {1}, {2}...
    $id, # first argument goes {0}
    $link, # second goes {1}
    $timeunixseconds ) # third goes {2}, etc etc

$isUriOk = [System.Uri]::IsWellFormedUriString($uriSting, [System.UriKind]::Absolute)
```

`DateTimeOffset` class starting with some .net version (4.5th .net, 5th powershell, AFAIR) has `To(From)UnixTimeSeconds` and `To(From)UnixTimeMilliseconds` methods.

`DateTime` *(and Get-Date, which returns DateTime)* does not have such methods! Use `DateTimeOffset`.

---

And for your original case:
Inside double-quoted strings, variables (even simple, in my opinion) should be added in `$()` brackets:

```
"Hello, $($env:USERNAME), it's $(Get-Date -Format 'D') today!"
# Hello, User1, it's Aug 22 2020 today!
```

Single variables can be added without `$()` syntax, but I'd recommed add `$()` always.

Inside single-quoted strings, `$()` or `$var` does not work:

```
'Hello, $($env:USERNAME), it is $(Get-Date -Format "D") today!'
# Hello, $($env:USERNAME), it is $(Get-Date -Format "D") today!
```